# SQL Query: finding the 'day' value from a SQL DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the fields `timeout` and `timein`. I need to return a list of records where `timeout` is on a different day to `timein`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both dates are in the same month, then:

```
select * 
from table 
where DAY(timeout) <> DAY(timein0)
```

or

```
select * 
from table 
where DATEPART(day,timeout) <> DATAPART(day,timein) or
```

will work..

If, however, they can be in different months, then you need to compare the full dates. This should do that for you:

```
select *
from table
where DATEDIFF(day,timeout,timein) <> 0
```

Comment: NOTE: Both of these examples give the "day of month".  If you have data that can ever go form 1st-Jan to 1st-Feb, this approach will fail.  If (as is possible) you can *guarantee* that data will *never* extend to a whole month, even in extreme or problematic cases, it will work fine.  Various possible uses of DATEDIFF *won't* be susceptible to this problem.

Comment: I'd still leave the other answers as well, just note the behaviour.  DAY(timeout) <> DAY(timein) is quite tidy *if* the data behaves appropriately.

Comment: Or: cast(timein as DATE) <> cast(timeout as DATE)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table_name 
where datediff(dd,timein,timeout) > 0 (for day in greater then today)
```

if want next day time out then

```
select * 
from table_name 
where datediff(dd,timein,timeout) =1
```

Comment: Or, using the OPs phrased "on a different day", just use `<> 0`

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
select *
from table
where day(timeout) != day(timein);
```

Comment: Why post a MySQL link to a SQL-Server question?

Comment: This syntax is valid in mssql as well. Problem is that it is not comparing month and year as well